# How can I rotate image in UIScrollView?

Tags: ios

I used scrollview in my project for zoom. There is a view in scrollview. I can zoom using scrollview's delegate. Can I rotate my view using scrollview delagete, Or shall I use UIPinchGestureRecognizer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UIScrollView` already has a UIPinchGestureRecognizer for zooming and UIPanGestureRecognizer for panning (and has properties to access these).  I shouldn't need to use the `UIScrollViewDelegate` for nominal zooming or panning.  You just need to set the minimum and maximum zoom, and panning content size.  E.g.,

```
self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.5;
self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0;
self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2000.0 , 2000.0);
```

Comment: thanks for answer but i need pan.I am trying rotate images with two fingers. its named as pan i think.

Comment: +1 for the reminder of content size. I needed to set the HEIGHT of the content size to larger than the initial container view. In the zoom delegate I set the content size to the scroll size times the zoomScale so everything stays in synch.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are lots of tutorial explaining the pan and zoom in scrollview Here is one from [apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/UIScrollView_pg/ZoomZoom/ZoomZoom.html)

Comment: i cant see there how can i pan a view using uiscrollview?These are all about zoom, not pan(pan:rotate images with fingers).

Comment: @yatanadam : First make the question clearly.You can edit it there itself.